# Java Mail sender .mailcap not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application that is sending emails trough gmail. I have credentials setup and everything works fine on one machine, but throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User.mailcap (System cannot find the file) on a different machine. The code is exactly the same

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmailServiceUtils {

    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    //TODO change method to accept other variables as a hashmap

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, Map<String, String> templateVariables, String templateFilePath) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "utf-8");
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setSubject(subject);

        // Load and process the HTML template
        String htmlContent = loadAndProcessTemplate(templateVariables, templateFilePath);
        helper.setText(htmlContent, true);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }

    private String loadAndProcessTemplate(Map<String, String> templateVariables, String templateFilePath) {
        Context context = new Context();

        //Step through all items in templateVariables map and set them as variable for thymeleaf template
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : templateVariables.entrySet()) {
            context.setVariable(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        // Process the template with variables
        return templateEngine.process(templateFilePath, context);
    }

}
```

The error in question

```
2023-08-17T17:37:40.365+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.sun.mail.smtp                        : Using mechanism LOGIN
2023-08-17T17:37:40.636+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : MailcapCommandMap: load HOME
2023-08-17T17:37:40.637+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : Checking system property jakarta.activation.spi.MailcapRegistryProvider
2023-08-17T17:37:40.637+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       :   not found
2023-08-17T17:37:40.637+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : Using java.util.ServiceLoader to find jakarta.activation.spi.MailcapRegistryProvider
2023-08-17T17:37:40.638+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : ServiceProvider loading Facility used; returning object [org.eclipse.angus.activation.MailcapRegistryProviderImpl]
2023-08-17T17:37:40.639+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] angus.activation                         : new MailcapFile: file C:\Users\user\.mailcap
2023-08-17T17:37:40.639+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : MailcapRegistry: can't load from file - C:\Users\user\.mailcap

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\.mailcap (Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.angus.activation.MailcapFile.<init>(MailcapFile.java:71) ~[angus-activation-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.angus.activation.MailcapRegistryProviderImpl.getByFileName(MailcapRegistryProviderImpl.java:29) ~[angus-activation-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap.loadFile(MailcapCommandMap.java:284) ~[jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap.<init>(MailcapCommandMap.java:154) ~[jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at jakarta.activation.CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(CommandMap.java:60) ~[jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.getCommandMap(DataHandler.java:128) ~[jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:590) ~[jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:290) ~[jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:316) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1580) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1177) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:510) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1538) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1177) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:510) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1538) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2265) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2225) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:459) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at com.voucherservice.evoucher.Utils.EmailServiceUtils.sendEmail(EmailServiceUtils.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.voucherservice.evoucher.Service.Impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl.register(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:83) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at com.voucherservice.evoucher.Performance.PerformanceLoggingAspect.logPerformance(PerformanceLoggingAspect.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at com.voucherservice.evoucher.Service.Impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.register(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.voucherservice.evoucher.Controller.AuthenticationController.register(AuthenticationController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at com.voucherservice.evoucher.Configuration.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-08-17T17:37:40.641+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : MailcapCommandMap: load SYS
2023-08-17T17:37:40.641+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : Checking system property jakarta.activation.spi.MailcapRegistryProvider
2023-08-17T17:37:40.642+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       :   not found
2023-08-17T17:37:40.642+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : Using java.util.ServiceLoader to find jakarta.activation.spi.MailcapRegistryProvider
2023-08-17T17:37:40.642+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : ServiceProvider loading Facility used; returning object [org.eclipse.angus.activation.MailcapRegistryProviderImpl]
2023-08-17T17:37:40.642+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] angus.activation                         : new MailcapFile: file C:\Users\user\.jdks\corretto-17.0.7\conf\mailcap
2023-08-17T17:37:40.643+02:00 DEBUG 10472 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] jakarta.activation                       : MailcapRegistry: can't load from file - C:\Users\user\.jdks\corretto-17.0.7\conf\mailcap
```

This is an odd error as the same app with the same configuration works on one system and then fails on another.

Comment: Well - *C:\Users\user\.mailcap* **Is** that file present?